# How can docker-compose be used to build Dockerfiles?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

I have such structure :

[image]

In my Makefile, I build the dockerfile:

```
sudo docker build --build-arg PHP_VERSION=7.4 -t kaiza/image-php74 - < dockerfile/Dockerfile.php
```

And *kaiza/image-php74* is well created locally, if i do `docker images`, i get:

[image]

Then, in my docker-compose.php74.yml :

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  php7.4:
    image: "kaiza/image-php74"
    container_name: "kz-php74"
    hostname: "kz-php74"
    user: 1000:1000
...
```

But, when I run it

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose/php/docker-compose.php74.yml up --build -d
```

I get this error :

***"pull access denied for kaiza/image-php74, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied"***

Anyone have any idea how I can solve this without going through the **registry** solution (to keep everything local)?

Thanks.

Comment: You'd need to build `kaiza/image-php74` locally. Docker always checks if it already has it locally and if not trys to pull it. Docker-Compose does not build images, it just uses them!

Comment: what is `kaiza/image-php74`? It does not exist on the public docker hub. If it's not in a private repository, it should exist locally. Has the image been built locally? Please check with the command below. `docker images | grep kaiza/image-php74`

Comment: @Deitsch I built it like : `sudo docker build --build-arg PHP_VERSION=7.4 -t kaiza/image-php74 - < dockerfile/Dockerfile.php`

Comment: @myeongkilkim I get a result :

`kaiza/image-php74           latest        37f36003df04   15 hours ago    258MB`

Answer (score 10):

docker-compose can be used as part of your workflow to build Dockerfiles.

A nice way to arrange this is to have a docker-compose.yml in the root, and then have a sub folder for each service.

`compose.yml`

```yaml
services:
  php7.4:
    image: kaiza/image-php74:latest
    build:
      context: php74
      args:
        PHP_VERSION: ${VERSION-7.3}
```

Assuming the relative path from the docker-compose to the php74 Dockerfile is php74/Dockerfile then:

`docker-compose build php7.4` will build, and tag the image as kaiza/image-php74, and `docker-compose up` or `docker-compose run php7.4` will build the image if requred, or use the locally built image if available.

The full reference for the build section is available on [github](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/build.md)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. doing `docker-compose build php7.4` is equivalent to `docker build --build-arg PHP_VERSION=7.4 -t kaiza/image-php74 - < dockerfile/Dockerfile.php`,  isn't it?

this can be a lead however Dockerfile.php has a PHP_VERSION argument; how will I be able to pass it from docker-compose?

Comment: using `args:` in `build:` component like `build: args: PHP_VERSION: 7.4`

Comment: Added a link to the full reference on github and an example of using args, along with a defaulted environment arg.

Comment: The [build reference is also available on docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/).